# FreeMat : How different is it from Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, freemat

Have been looking for an alternative to MatLab...found working on Octave quite difficult...missing the debugging capabilities of MatLab...Came across FreeMat...wanted to know how is FreeMat different from Octave...is it just a graphical frontend to Octave like QtOctave (which I'm yet to explore) or is it more than that? What additional capabilities does it provide? What would be a better use of time - investing in FreeMat or makign do with Octave using tools like QtOctave (matlab not an option)?

Comment: For starters, look at the amount of times people have tagged questions here on SO with Matlab (15k times), Octave (~800 times) and Freemat (6 times, including your own). That's a fair hint towards the size of the Freemat community :)

Comment: Freemat is not just a front-end to octave, but a standalone program. Do not forget to consider [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org) as alternatives.

Comment: QtOctave is abandoned, it doesn't work with new version of Octave. If your problem is missing the debug buttons from matlab (Octave has the commands, just not the buttons), try its experimental GUI. That's if you're looking for a matlab replacement with same syntax. If keeping the syntax is not a requirement and you can learn a new language, there's much better options (Julia, Python (NumPy and SciPy) and R for example). Disclaimer: I'm an Octave developer.

Answer (score 7):

In short, both GNU Octave and FreeMat are open-source alternatives to MATLAB. However, Octave is more mature and has wider community support.

I also found [this interesting article](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~gobbert/papers/SharmaGobbertTR2010.pdf) that compares MATLAB, Octave, FreeMat and SciLab. It does point out a few issues against FreeMat:

1. It doesn't support some functions (such as [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) and [`pcg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcg.html)).
2. It has limited 3-D graphics capabilities (*e.g.* no support for the [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) function).
3. It is also lacking in the ODE department, for not having a state-of-the-art solver.

Essentially, this article concludes that Octave is indeed the most compatible with MATLAB at present.

Now, if you're searching for a good GUI/IDE, try one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#User_interfaces).

Comment: the last link has been removed.

Comment: @Foad Thanks. I've deleted the broken link from my answer.

Comment: It would be great if someone could add [Nelson Numerical Software](https://github.com/Nelson-numerical-software/nelson) and [OpenMatrix Language (OML)](https://www.openmatrix.org/) to this comparison.